# Receiver function not being found in a Go application

Tags: function, go

I am struggling to work out why a receiver function in a go application isn't being found.

I'm comparing my code to other tutorial code as for the life of me can't see the problem.

I have a struct in main.go called application and am creating an instance of it in the main function.

```
type application struct {
    cnf    cnf
    logger *log.Logger
}

....

func main {
...
app := &application{
        cnf:    cfg,
        logger: logger,
    }
...
```

In the same main.go file I have other functions that are function receivers that seem to be working fine, but I have one function in a separate file, in package main with the signature

```
func (app *application) sendSlackMessage(msg string) error {}
```

but, when I try and call it from another function in main, like so

```
err := app.sendSlackMessage(fmt.Sprintf("MESSAGE"))
```

I get an error

```
app.sendSlackMessage undefined (type *application has no field or method SendSlackMessage)
```

I'm not sure if the issue is that its in another file (although the tutorial code does that) or what the issues is.

Comment: Are you, by any chance, executing the code with `go run main.go`? i.e. compiling and running a specific file instead of the whole package? [`go run` docs](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program)

Comment: Use `go build` and stay away from tutorials telling you to use `go run main.go`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Running `go run main.go` will compile and execute *only* the `main.go` file. Any other `.go` files in that package will be left out.

Instead try running one of:

- `go run .`
- `go run *.go`
- `go run my/cmd`
- `go build -o ./main && ./main`

---

https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Compile_and_run_Go_program

> Run compiles and runs the named main Go package. Typically the package
> is specified as **a list of .go source files** from a single directory,
> but it may also be **an import path**, **file system path**, or **pattern
> matching a single known package**, as in 'go run .' or 'go run my/cmd'.

Comment: `go run .` being almost universally preferred over `go run *.go`, since it will honor build tags.