# Using function from `main` package into main.go file

Tags: go, import, package

I have 2 files into the root directory: `main.go` and `utils.go`.

`main.go` file is:

```
package main

func main() {
   CustomPrint()
}
```

`utils.go` file:

```
package main

import "fmt"

func CustomPrint() {
   fmt.Println("example")
}
```

However, I get an error because `customPrint` is not recognized.

Is there any way to do that without create another package to store `utils.go` file?

Comment: This is because you are executing the program as `go run main.go`, which processes only the `main.go` file. Give the tool all the files of the program and you'll be ok. See https://stackoverflow.com/a/68631100/965900

Answer (score 1):

It's Simple actually, When you try to run "go run main.go", You only execute the main.go file. Utils.go file is not executed together with it.

First you can just execute

```
go run
```

it will prompt you error.

[As you can see that is expect list and multiple files instead of single file, "No go files listed"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PLowv.png)

The solution is you just need to execute both files

```
go run main.go utils.go
```

There you go problem solved!

it will behave as you expected.

Second option is simpler which you do not have to type so many files.

You can run

```
go run ./
```

it will executed every .go files in your current directory